# Entity Framework data annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public partial class SystemUser
{
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pass")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Type { get; set; }
}
```

When query from database using this statement, data annotations are working fine:

```
context.SystemUsers.ToList();
```

but when I use 'new' keyword in my query, data annotation are automatically ignored.

```
context.SystemUsers.Select(u=> new
{
    u.Username,
    u.Type
});
```

I want to use second query that I told and prevent from data annotaion ignore
what's the solution?

Comment: Using the `new` keyword, you're creating a new **anonymous** types - and that anonymous type doesn't have any data annotations on it...... if you want to create a new `SystemUser` object and use its data annotations, use `new SystemUser { ..... }`

Comment: your `u` corresponds to `SystemUser`. so `u.Username` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I use 'new' keyword in my query, data annotation are automatically ignored

Those data annotations are expressed only on the `SystemUser` type.  But your `.Select()` clause is transforming the objects into a new anonymous type.  It may have the same intuitive structure as a `SystemUser` (same property names/types/etc.), but as a statically typed language it is decidedly *not* a `SystemUser` object.

In order to use the `SystemUser` type, you have to select into that type:

```
context.SystemUsers.Select(u => new SystemUser
{
    Username = u.Username,
    Type = u.Type
});
```

Comment: but how I convert it ToList?
entity framework error on this

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'StoreModel.SystemUser' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @Mohammad: What did you try?  Appending `.ToList()` to the end of that should do the trick.  Conversely, you can use `.ToList()` *before* the `.Select()`, which essentially would materialize the entire table and then remove Entity Framework from the concern.  *Normally* that's not a good idea and should be done very carefully, but in this case you're already materializing the entire table so it doesn't seem like it would be a problem here.

Comment: one more problem
i dont select password column but query have it.why?
i dont need it

Comment: @Mohammad: That's an effect of materializing the list before transforming the data. It's going to select every column. If you *really* want to tweak it, and if Entity Framework *really* doesn't like selecting into a new `SystemUser`, then you might combine both approaches into something longer: `context.SystemUsers.Select(u => new { Username = u.Username, Type = u.Type }).ToList().Select(u => new SystemUser { Username = u.Username, Type = u.Type }).ToList()` It's *probably* overkill, but basically it removes the password from the expression tree, materializes, then transforms to `SelectUser`s.

Comment: @Mohammad: Specify exactly what you tried and where it is "shown".

Comment: public IEnumerable<object> GetAll()
        {
            var Users = Ctx.SystemUsers.Select(u=> new
            {
                u.Username,
                u.Type
            }).ToList().Select(u => new SystemUser
            {
                Username = u.Username,
                Type = u.Type
            });

            return Users.ToList();
        }

it shown on datagrid but only column and have no value

Comment: @Mohammad: If the data grid is auto-constructing columns from the backing data then it's going to create a column for every field.  The fact that it's empty means the data is *not* being shown.  If you don't want the UI to include that column, remove it from the UI.

Comment: datagrid automatically generate field I dont design column for it

Comment: in fact this query contain password
is there any way to remove it from query?

Comment: @Mohammad: Either bind the grid to an object which has the columns you want to display, or define the columns from this object that you want to display.  The system has no way of knowing that you personally don't want to display a specific field, you have to tell it.  As for the query, where does this query contain the password?  Please be specific.

Comment: when we create new SystemUser automatically password come to query.
one way is use dataannotation AutoGenerateField = False but i dont want use this

Comment: @Mohammad: What do you mean by "password come to query".  You have to be specific about what the problem is.  Don't assume that I know anything about your system.  If that problem is *different* from what this question originally asked, you may consider asking a new question where you can more effectively specify the details of that problem.

Comment: context.SystemUsers.Select(u => new { Username = u.Username, Type = u.Type }).ToList().Select(u => new SystemUser { Username = u.Username, Type = u.Type }).ToList()

when we create new SystemUser in query new object created that we only set value to two properties of it.in fact password has null value

Comment: @Mohammad: What exactly are you asking?  The `SystemUser` object has a `Password` property.  If you're not *setting* that property, then it's going to have an *empty* value.  The *entire point* of what you've been asking has been to build a list of `SystemUser` objects without populating the `Password` property, and now you're asking why the `Password` property hasn't been populated?

Comment: exactly I dont want password property for datagrid

Comment: @Mohammad: *Then remove it from the data grid.*  I don't know how to be any more clear about that.  If you want to change your user interface, then a great way to do that would be to change your user interface.  You have two options, which I've already stated: (1) Bind the grid to a collection of objects which have only the properties you want to display and auto-generate the grid's columns; or (2) Bind the grid to the `SystemUser` objects and manually define the grid's columns.  Either of those options will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data annotation then write as below:

```
context.SystemUsers.Select(u=> new SystemUser
{
    u.Username,
    u.Type
});
```

Because you have provided details in your `SystemUser` view modal and if you create using only `new` then it creates anonymous object which does not contain data annotation.